How to Create an Android Widget with Two-Way Data Binding for a Counter Component in an Ionic Angular App?
I'm working on an Ionic Angular project using Ionic 8 and Angular 18. I have a counter component in my app, and I would like to create an Android widget for it. The widget should be able to display the counter value and allow the user to increment or decrement the counter directly from the widget.
Requirements:
The widget should display the current counter value.
Users should be able to interact with the widget to increment or decrement the counter.
Changes made from the widget should be reflected in the app (two-way data binding).
If the counter value is changed in the app, it should also update in the widget.
I've already developed the counter component in my Ionic app, but I'm not sure how to proceed with creating an Android widget that communicates with my Ionic app to achieve two-way data binding.
Questions:
What steps do I need to follow to create an Android widget that interacts with my Ionic Angular app?
How can I achieve two-way data binding between the Android widget and my Ionic Angular app?
Are there any specific libraries or plugins that I need to use to achieve this functionality?
Any guidance or example code would be highly appreciated!

Please clarify what you mean by "Android widget".  Are you referring to a Android Home Screen App Widget: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/overview or something else.

Yes. I want  Android Home Screen App Widget.

You need something like Ionic portals to create a native webview: https://ionic.io/docs/portals. Good luck!
